# Как правильно сделать такой блок?

Tags: css, css3

Как сделать такой правый нижний угол, как на картинке, подкинь-те идею

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Подложите под блок с "зелено-синим" фоном блок с красным фоном (можно псевдоэлементом, если не хотите создавать доп элемент), и задайте каждому соответсвующий border-radius

```css
.green {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #ADFFEB;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 20px 20px 60px 20px;
 }
 
 .green::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  background-color: #f00;
  border-radius: 22px 22px 0 22px;
 }
```

```html
<div class="green"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 35px 35px 0 35px;
}

.block {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: green;
  border-radius: 35px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="block"></div>
</div>
```